# Installing scripts on IDA Pro

Tags: scripting, reverse-engineering, disassembly, ida

Around the net I've seen reference to ["scripts" for IDA Pro](http://www.openrce.org/downloads/browse/IDA_Scripts), but can't work out how to load or install them for [IDA Pro 4.9 Freeware Version](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/idadownfreeware.htm).

How do I do this? In particular I wish to use [PE Scripts](http://www.openrce.org/downloads/details/57/PE_Scripts).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If those scripts are IDC scripts, they can be loaded from with `File -> IDC File...`.

If this item does not exist, then probably this feature is disabled in the free version.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really install script for IDA Pro. You just point IDA Pro to them scripts.

Some script file have special consideration for IDA Pro, such as ida.idc, onload.idc, etc...

You can run an IDC from the command line too with the -Sscript.idc switch